# How to call a COBOL batch program from a COBOL stored procedure on DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, cobol

Quick disclaimer: I'm a .Net developer and may not have provided all the information you need about the environment, but can get the information on request. We have COBOL programmers, but they have never done this.

We are converting a mainframe application with a DB2 database to a .Net MVC application with SQL database. There is one mainframe COBOL batch program that we would like to call from a COBOL stored procedure on the DB2. I've read this can be done, but I haven't found a good example of how to create a COBOL stored procedure that calls a COBOL program. The COBOL batch program takes about 5 input parameters, but does not return anything.

We already have a linked server that we are using to call native sql stored procedures on DB2 from a SQL server.

**Edited for future reference below**

We looked into two ways of solving our problem - creating a COBOL stored procedure that could be used by DB2-mainframe running on z/os where we'd copy/paste our COBOL from the CICS program and tweak it to run as a stored procedure (thus cutting out CICS completely) or using CICS to host a web service end point that can call to the CICS program we wanted to invoke, much like described on [slide 21 of this PowerPoint](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpublic.dhe.ibm.com%2Fsoftware%2Fhtp%2Fcics%2Ftserver%2FCICS_TS3.1_WebServices.ppt&ei=X_4VU5z9FqLCyQHoioHABg&usg=AFQjCNGHICyd-iWSU4falRtLCssVOBr2KA&sig2=QzRpmy2Eg8E6ZKlggNFxqw&bvm=bv.62286460,d.aWc&cad=rjt).

We have decided to move forward with the second option because there is precedent for doing it that way already, so it's going to be the easier path for us.

Comment: Where are you having difficulty?  Defining the stored procedure or writing the COBOL stored procedure?  Do you want to CALL the batch program or are you looking to execute a jobstream (JCL) that executes the batch program?

Comment: I could use both a high-level explanation (bullet points including any considerations security-wise to get DB2 to talk to a mainframe) and it would be great to get a reference to somewhere on the web that shows an example of this, or to documentation describing it. When I talk to the COBOL programmers on our team they tell me they've never done it before, and don't know what to do, so I want to help them out.

Comment: From "get DB2 to talk to a mainframe" it sounds like you want a stored procedure in DB2 on LUW to call a program (not a stored procedure) on System z, is that correct?  This is markedly different from your original question.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to be much more exact about what is where. Are you using DB2 LUW? Or does the DB2 you refer to in your question remain on z/OS? What does the batch COBOL program do? Does it use SQL? Files? If you're replacing the system, why can't you just replace that program? Why would you want to use it? Why does it need to be on the Mainframe?

Comment: Thanks for your questions! I am starting to see why there are no examples to be found anywhere. I'll dig in some more and see what I can find out to help illuminate it. From my point of view, it seems like it would be a straight forward thing. Write a cobol stored procedure on DB2 that calls a COBOL batch program on the mainframe, but you've helped me to see that it isn't.

Comment: Well, glad you're happy. You originally asked about a batch program. You still have DB2 on z/OS *and* as LUW, it seems. Still not clear your possibly-circuitous route is the best, but can only guess, since we never found out what the program you are using does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question!

I was thinking of why not let your LUW DB2 stored procedure call a transaction manager which will execute your cobol program? This if you use a transaction manager in mainframe (which I assume you do!). If you are not familiar with this, just check your mainframe guys if you use transaction manager as CICS or IMS.

I have not done this, but it should work.

(alternative, call a http/webservice from db2 sp which will execute an ims transaction that executes your cobol program...)

I must add that I ve not tried any of above, I have´nt used db2 luw. But maybe the ideas are worth to mention here?

Comment: Marked this as correct because we have decided to go the route you suggested - calling the web service, much like [slide 21 of this PowerPoint deck](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpublic.dhe.ibm.com%2Fsoftware%2Fhtp%2Fcics%2Ftserver%2FCICS_TS3.1_WebServices.ppt&ei=X_4VU5z9FqLCyQHoioHABg&usg=AFQjCNGHICyd-iWSU4falRtLCssVOBr2KA&sig2=QzRpmy2Eg8E6ZKlggNFxqw&bvm=bv.62286460,d.aWc&cad=rjt) describes.

Comment: happy for your feedback, good luck and let us know the progress.